# How to install Ruby 2.0.0 on mac os x 10.8.2 using RVM without MacPorts or Homebrew?

Tags: ruby, compilation, openssl, rvm

I know I can install Hombrew or Macports and then update the old OpenSSL (0.9.8) but I don't want to do that.

- I only want to install ruby 2.0.0 and then rails
- I don't want to install Homebrew or Macports

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this post at coderwall](https://coderwall.com/p/tptocq), use the following commands:

```
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm install 2.0.0 \ 
    --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr \
    --verify-downloads 1
```

Also, depending on your `rvm` configuration, you may want to add the `--autolibs=0` option to each `rvm` command above so it doesn't try to use a package manager (like macports or homebrew).

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with command:

```
rvm install ruby-head
```